# Add a description to site proposals?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, site-proposal, site-description

Currently, Area 51 site proposals can only contain their title and the "Proposed Q&A site for ..." section.

How about adding a description field where the proposal author can detail a little more what the site's topic and purpose should be?

Answer (score 3):

I use the comments, the first comment can be your description

Comment: That's the same I do, I was only asking if this could be integrated into the proposal.